# error division by zero spelling sugestion

Tags: python, spell-checking, divide-by-zero, autocorrect

```
for word in typo.keys():
    for sug in typo[word].getSuggestion().keys():
        #todo
        s = (typo[word].getErrorIndexFront() - 1) + (len(word) - typo[word].getErrorIndexRear() + `enter code here`1)
        n1 = len(word)enter code here
        n2 = len(sug)
        u1 = 0
        u2 = 0
        if n1 == n2:
            u1 = len(word[(typo[word].getErrorIndexFront() - 1):(len(word) typo[word].getErrorIndexRear() + 1)])
            u2 = u1
        else:
            u2 = abs(n2 - n1)
  
        typo[word].getSuggestion()[sug] = ((s ^ 2) - ((n2 - n1) ^ 2) - ((u1 + u2) ^ 2)) / (s ^ 2)                          
          
        print(typo[word].getSuggestion()[sug])


    for k,v in list(typo[word].getSuggestion().items()):
        if v <= 0:
            del typo[word].getSuggestion()[k]

    #print(typo[word].getSuggestion())


print("time = ",(time.time() - startTime)," s")
```

---

ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
13             u2 = abs(n2 - n1)
14
---> 15         typo[word].getSuggestion()[sug] = ((s ^ 2) - ((n2 - n1) ^ 2) - ((u1 + u2) ^ 2)) / (s ^ 2)
16
17         print(typo[word].getSuggestion()[sug])

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero`enter code here`

Comment: Could you please add some more information about what your code is supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

^ is not square; ** is

^ is bitwise xor operation